# Unable to start a react-native app in simulator

Tags: facebook, react-native

I am trying to follow the official [react-native tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content).  Everything goes fine until I try to run the project. A bash script then pops up with the following error message

```
~/react_sites/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/packager ~

/Users/Chris/react_sites/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:74
  const setupEnvScript = /^win/.test(process.platform)
  ^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
~
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

and the simulator gives a `Could not connect to development server` error. How do I fix this?

I am using Xcode 7.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have the [pre-requisites](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#requirements), but double check before moving on. Homebrew, Watchman, Node 4+, and Flow (optional).

When you open the project in Xcode and push build button (play?), it should start the packager server automatically. But in your case, it doesn't seem to have. In that case, try running `npm start` in the terminal from your project's root before building the project.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using older version of node.js, you should install node.js 4.0 or higher.

please refer to https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: I am using node.js 5.0.0